# Htaccess pretty url structure within sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite urls inside of a sub-directory.

I want to make my URLS look pretty heres a example of what I have

mywebsite.com/test/index.php?page=the-rest-of-the-url

I want to look like

mywebsite.com/test/the-rest-of-the-url

```
 #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test/ [NC]
 #RewriteRule ^test(/.*)?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /test/index.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This code works except that it messes with my other rewrite conditions. It doesn't seem to just be targeting my folder test.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out. I didn't realize I needed to have a seperate htaccess file inside of my sub directory.